# Uniform Grid as Panel Template for All Items in ItemsControl Except the First

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface, itemscontrol

I'm working on a progress wizard. I defined it as a style based on the ItemsControl. I have an ItemTemplateSelector with two DataTemplates, one for the first item and one for the rest of the items. I have it working correctly except for one really small issue that is super tricky to fix. There is a gap between the first item and the second item. [image]
This is what the control should look like: [image] The gap occurs because I'm using a uniform grid and so all of the columns are sized the same, even though the first one has no line. Using a uniform grid is important though because I want everything on one row and I want the control to stretch to fill the available space as it grows. I've tried not using the uniform grid but I end up either having issues with the margins or with not filling the available space. how can I fix this gap?

Here's the code:

```
<Style x:Key="WizardProgressBar" TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="FirstItem">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Ellipse Name="ellipse"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Width="32"  />
                </Grid>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Completed}" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="ellipse" Property="Stroke" Value="{DynamicResource DisabledBrush}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding InProgress}" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="ellipse" Property="Stroke" Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryTextBrush}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>


            <DataTemplate x:Key="OtherItem">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Ellipse Name="ellipse"  Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Width="32" />
                    <Line Name="leftPath" Grid.Column="0" X1="0" Y1="16" 
                              X2="{Binding ActualWidth, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}}" Y2="16" />
                </Grid>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Completed}" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="ellipse" Property="Stroke" Value="{DynamicResource DisabledBrush}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="leftPath" Property="Stroke" Value="{DynamicResource DisabledBrush}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding InProgress}" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="ellipse" Property="Stroke" Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryTextBrush}"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="leftPath" Property="Stroke" Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryTextBrush}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Style.Resources>
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Rows="1"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplateSelector">
            <Setter.Value>
                <wpf:ItemsDataTemplateSelector  FirstItem="{StaticResource FirstItem}" OtherItem="{StaticResource OtherItem}" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

```
public class ItemsDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate FirstItem { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate OtherItem { get; set; }

        public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            var itemsControl = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(container);
            var returnTemplate = (itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(container) == 0) ? FirstItem : OtherItem;
            return returnTemplate;
        }
    }
```

Comment: UniformGrid is not a suitable ItemsPanel here, since its behavior is not what you want (it has no notion of "except the first"). You may however write your own Panel class. As a note, you don't need a DataTemplateSelector. Instead, add an ItemContainerStyle (for ContentPresenter) that sets the ContentTemplate property to OtherItem, and that has a Trigger on `ItemsControl.AlternationIndex` that sets ContentTemplate to FirstItem when the Trigger Value is zero. Also set AlternationCount to a high value (like 2147483647) on the ItemsControl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that the first item in your setup actually must have a different width compared to the other items. This is impossible with an `UniformGrid`.

I can suggest you the following solution.

The target configuration will look like this:

```
|··O––|––O––|––O––|––O··|
```

You will have a half-cell wide margin on the left and on the right (represented by the dots above). If you want, you can leverage them by specifying the margins of your control.

Also, we can simplify your data templates. Actually, we don't need separate templates for the first and the other items. See below.

### Setup

There are three tricks we're going to use here:

- the `ItemsControl.AlternationIndex` property to obtain the first element in the `ItemsControl`
- a `Canvas` to allow the connecting lines to be drawn outside of the corresponding `UniforGrid`'s cells
- a special `IValueConverter` that will help us calculate the needed line position

Now, this is the style for your `ItemsControl`:

```
<Style x:Key="WizardProgressBar" TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
  <Style.Resources>
    <local:LinearConverter x:Key="Multiplier" Scale="-0.5" Offset="16"/>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:YourItemType}">
      <Grid>            
        <Canvas>
          <Rectangle x:Name="leftPath" Height="2" Stroke="Blue" Canvas.Top="16"
                     Canvas.Left="{Binding Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource Multiplier}}"
                     Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContentPresenter}}}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Ellipse Name="ellipse" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="32" Width="32" Stroke="Blue"/>
      </Grid>
      <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
          <Setter TargetName="leftPath" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Completed}" Value="False">
          <Setter TargetName="ellipse" Property="Stroke" Value="{DynamicResource DisabledBrush}" />
          <Setter TargetName="leftPath" Property="Stroke" Value="{DynamicResource DisabledBrush}" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding InProgress}" Value="True">
          <Setter TargetName="ellipse" Property="Stroke" Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryTextBrush}"/>
          <Setter TargetName="leftPath" Property="Stroke" Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryTextBrush}" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
  </Style.Resources>
  <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <UniformGrid Rows="1"/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
  <Setter Property="AlternationCount" Value="100"/>
</Style>
```

Note the following changes:

- there is only one `DataTemplate`, no need for two different ones
- no need for template selector anymore
- we need a special converter in our style (code below)
- the `Ellipse` and the line (as a `Rectangle`) are placed in an 1x1 `Grid` into the same cell
- the line itself sits in a `Canvas`
- the `Ellipse` is centered horizontally
- there is an additional `Trigger` that catches the `AlternationIndex` value 0 and hides the line - it's for the first element
- the style sets the `AlternationCount` to 100 supposing you will have 100 wizard pages at maximum

Here is the converter:

```
class LinearConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public double Scale { get; set; }

    public double Offset { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // TODO: exception handling
        return System.Convert.ToDouble(value) * Scale + Offset;
    }

    // ConvertBack just throws a NotImplementedException
}
```

### Explanation

Each `Ellipse` represents a wizard page and is placed in center of the corresponding `UniformGrid`'s cell. The lines are placed to the left of the ellipses. The lines' width is set to the width of the `UnifiormGrid`'s single cell, and their horizontal position in the `Canvas` is set according to the formula: `WidthOfEllipse / 2 - WidthOfCell / 2`. This ensures the correct placement.

For the first wizard page, the line will be hidden.

Note that you might want to use `Fill` for the ellipses to hide the underlying lines.

Comment: This solution is very helpful. I was considering doing something like this. Is there any way you know of though that would allow me to remove or hide that half-cell wide margin on the left and on the right?

Comment: @user2481095, As I mentioned in the answer, you can use the `Margin` property to leverage those unwanted free spaces. Set your `ItemControl`'s `Margin` to negative offsets left and right, something like `Margin="-50,0,-50,0"`. You can even set this property directly in the `Style` and calculate this margin dynamically, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution is to remove the first one from the ItemsControl.

```
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="WizardProgressBar" TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
            <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Ellipse Name="ellipse"  Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Width="32" />
                            <Line Name="leftPath" Grid.Column="0" X1="0" Y1="16" 
                          X2="{Binding ActualWidth, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}}" Y2="16" />
                        </Grid>
                        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Completed}" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="ellipse" Property="Stroke" Value="Gray" />
                                <Setter TargetName="leftPath" Property="Stroke" Value="Gray"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding InProgress}" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="ellipse" Property="Stroke" Value="Black"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="leftPath" Property="Stroke" Value="Black"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <UniformGrid Rows="1"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Ellipse Name="ellipse"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Width="32" Stroke="Black"/>
    <ItemsControl Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource WizardProgressBar}"
                  x:Name="otherItemsGrid">
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: That doesn't correctly form the control I need to create. I edited the description to make my requirements a bit more clear.

Answer (score -1):

To quote Steve Jobs: *"It’s not just what it looks like and feels like. Design is how it works."*.

We can visualize one step in the progress by placing the previous node, the intermediate path and the next node on one grid cell. Below five cells, and the five corresponding phases the user has to complete.

```
 ___________________________________________________________
|           |           |           |           |           |
O - - - - - O - - - - - O - - - - - O - - - - - O - - - - - O
|___________|___________|___________|___________|___________|
```

Once an intermediate path is in progress, the previous node has been completed (fully drawn). And after it is completed, both the path and the next node can be fully drawn as well.

The beauty of this approach lies in its simplicity and the fact that there are no special cases or exceptions. Every phase is handled exactly the same, both in the view and in the model behind it.

The first node is where we start (progressing to the second). Think about it, you don't want to start in tin air, you start at the first node in the chain, moving on to the next. If there are five progressions, there'll be six nodes.

In terms of the brushes you referenced:

```
                    Default                 In progress             Completed

Left node           DisabledBrush           PrimaryTextBrush        PrimaryTextBrush

Intermediate path   DisabledBrush           DisabledBrush           PrimaryTextBrush

Right node          DisabledBrush           DisabledBrush           PrimaryTextBrush
```

The only *draw*back is you'll be drawing every node twice, except for the first and the last.

Comment: This was a good attempt at providing a good answer, to the wrong question. the askers questions mainly relate to getting the positioning right, rather then how to draw the lines as their state changes. A more concrete implementation would probably have scored higher.